# onClick at XML can't see method from viewmodel using Room & databinding

Tags: android, android-room, android-databinding

It seems I have some problem with kapt. I study Android and try to create app with Room and Coroutines.
I get this kind of mistakes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhQb5.png)
and my onclicklistener at XML is underlined with red, and the mistake here is "Cannot find identifier 'onSave' ".
I also tried to set onclick listener at the fragment, but I got the same mistakes.
Neither invalidating caches nor rebuilding project helps.

AddViewModel.kt:

```
`package com.example.memorizewords.add

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.*
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.Companion.APPLICATION_KEY
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras
import com.example.memorizewords.database.Word
import com.example.memorizewords.database.WordDatabase
import com.example.memorizewords.database.WordDatabaseDao
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

class AddViewModel(
    val database: WordDatabaseDao?,
    application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val _targetWord = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val _nativeWord = MutableLiveData<String>()


    private suspend fun insert(word: Word) {
        database?.insert(word)
    }

    private fun onSave() {
        runBlocking {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {}
            // val newWord = Word(0L, _targetWord.value!!, _nativeWord.value!!, true)
            val newWord = Word(0L, "String", "String", true)
            insert(newWord)
        }

    }

    companion object {

        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
                modelClass: Class<T>,
                extras: CreationExtras
            ): T {
                val application = checkNotNull(extras[APPLICATION_KEY])
                val dataSource = WordDatabase.getInstance(application).WordDatabaseDao
                AddViewModel(dataSource, application)

                return AddViewModel(dataSource, application) as T
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

AddFragment.kt:

```
`package com.example.memorizewords.add

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import com.example.memorizewords.R
import com.example.memorizewords.databinding.FragmentAddBinding


class AddFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: AddViewModel by viewModels { AddViewModel.Factory }
    lateinit var targetWord: String
    lateinit var nativeWord: String

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        val binding: FragmentAddBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_add, container, false)

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        binding.addViewModel = viewModel


}`
```

XML:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="addViewModel"
            type="com.example.memorizewords.add.AddViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/targetBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin_left_right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/button_margin_left_right"
        android:hint="@string/enterTarget"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nativeBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin_left_right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/button_margin_left_right"
        android:hint="@string/enterNative"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/save_button_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/save_button_margin"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
        android:onClick="@{() -> addViewModel.onSave()}" //onSave here is underlined with red
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>`
```

module's build.gradle

```
`plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.memorizewords"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Android KTX
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'

    // Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'

    // Room and Lifecycle dependencies
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"


    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3")

    // Coroutines
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1"
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1"

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
}`
```

app's build.gradle

```
`plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.4.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`
```